# Homeomorphisms on the plane either preserve or reverse orientation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Note that any Jordan curve in $\mathbb R^2$ can be oriented either anticlockwise or clockwise.
Let $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ be a homeomorphism.
How can we prove the following fact: The mapping $f$ either preserves orientation of all Jordan curves or reverses orientation of all Jordan curves?
(A reference helps as well)

Comment: Do you know the concept of winding number?

Comment: Yes, I do know the concept.

Comment: I would use local homology for this proof. Are you familiar with this notion?

Comment: Yes, I also know what it is as well!